# How to Create a Global Variable in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

**Scenario:**
I have a JSON file that has around 4,000 key-value pairs in an object. In a CodeIgniter helper function I get this file's contents, use `json_decode()` to convert the contents to PHP Object and return the Object.

**Code Snippet**

```
function get_characters()
{
    $json_url = base_url('keywords.json'); // path to JSON file
    $json_data = file_get_contents($json_url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    return json_decode($json_data); // decode and return the JSON content
}
```

**Question 1:** Will calling this function over and over again hamper the performance since the JSON file is read every time the function is called?

**Question 2:** If it hampers the performance, how can I store the output of this function one time in a global variable so that I can use it across my application? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code snippet will be helpful

Comment: @Vishal, I've added the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You should include your code snippet in the question. No worries, I have an answer for you. I hope it may help you to do the job.

Answer 1: Obviously.

Answer 2: Of course there is a lot of way to do so. You should assign the output to CI superglobal variable as follows:

```
//Your helper function may look like..
if (!function_exists('load_my_json_file'))
{
    function load_my_json_file()
    {
        $my_json = file_get_contents('./my_json.json');
        $my_json_obj = json_decode($my_json);

        //Grab the CodeIgniter native resource
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->my_json_obj = $my_json_obj;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now you will be able to access your json object by calling `$this->my_json_obj` from controller, model or view.

An example is given below on how to call the helper function:

```
//app/core/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //Load your helper
        $this->load->helper('common');
        //Call the json loader function
        load_my_json_file();
    }

}
```

```
//controllers/Welcome.php
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->my_json_obj);
        exit();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the code snippet in the question. It is very similar to the code you've written in the answer. Yes, after implementing your answer I am able to access the variable globally in helpers as well as controllers. Can you explain what is happening in this line?
`$CI->my_json_obj = $my_json_obj;`

Comment: The main magic happens on `$CI = & get_instance();` statement. When we assign it, $CI refers to the main CI Controller instance. After then we just saving our json object to a property of Codeigniter Controller Instance by `$CI->my_json_obj = $my_json_obj;`

`get_instance()` is used to create 'Ancillary Classes'. Codeigniter has a well documentation on it: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably
2. You can't really. PHP doesn't persist data between requests (even session data is stored in files)

Probably the better solution is to use a RDBMS instead of a JSON file.